# Installing java program via CD

Tags: java, deployment, installation, software-distribution, cd

I have a program (java jar file) that I want to distribute on CDs. My friend told me that there are free/open-source CD installers available that automatically install your program onto the customer's computer.

Now I can't seem to find this on Google. So are there any CD installers that you would recommend that I can use (so I don't need to program one myself).

Outline:

My program consists of class files, sound files, source files (i'm open source) and images (packaged into a jar file).

I only need the installer to work for Windows computers.

Comment: Do you really need to "install" it (create registry entries, etc.)? Or is it more of a "Copy to Program Files and create a desktop shortcut" type thing?

Comment: To run Java based program all you need is [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: @jjiceman More of a "Copy to Program Files and create a desktop shortcut"

Comment: @Azi yes that is true, but I am required to have it "installed" to the computer so it can be used without the CD.

Comment: *"I want to distribute on CDs"*  What millennium are we in?  I have two machines capable of running J2SE, both of them have internet access, yet only one has a CD drive.  This millennium, distribute over the net.

Comment: Long story short, I am asked to have the "distribute on CD" option available, of course this is not going to be the main method of distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running into numerous end problems, I finished the job with the use of [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).
Very quick and easy to use. Creates an installer similar to the ones you would see in popular programs. Gives you (and the user) the ability to create Desktop Shortcuts, QuickLaunch Icons and Startup folders. Allows you to add license information etc. Very simple and intuitive interface, I didn't have to read any documentation!

A big con: Only makes installers for windows. That met my requirements, but may not work for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

I think [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) does something like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can look into Java WebStart which in Java 6 was enhanced to allow "launch-from-cd-and-install-to-harddrive" which mean that it can work as a very simple installer.

It requires a JVM already present.  You can put the redistributable JRE on the cd too.

Comment: Have you ever seen it work?  Does it require a trusted app.?  Do you have a link to the official source of that info? I've seen it before, but my Google-fu is on the fritz at the moment.

Comment: I've read the spec carefully, and noticed it mentioned, but not tried it.

Answer (score 1):

[Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) is what I have used as my installer. It is really lightweight and has a nice GUI that makes things simple for the developer (one reason I chose not to use IzPack).

**It makes things dead simple for both the developer and the user.**

Your jar file is wrapped in a exe launcher.
If an up to date JRE is not detected, a bundled JRE is used or the user is prompted to download via java.com/download

Really, I couldn't have asked for anything simpler/better. Although you might get more functionality out of IzPack, if you want something dirt quick that can do everything the everyday developer needs, go for Launch4J.

P.S. Their splash screen option is a nice bonus :)